# How to find old debug data(Logs) in report navigator in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Can i get the old Debug records from the report navigator in Xcode. There is no enough information in Report Navigator help, so i could not find it.

Is there any other way to find my old logs.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Xcode has a little clock icon at the bottom of that tab to "Show only recent reports"

[image]

You either have that selected or have recently cleared your derived data folder, which I believe would remove all of your build history as your logs are stored there.

Derived data folder is usually at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`